# Is there a reasonable K-grroup of Behrend’s absolutely convergent complexes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology, l-adic-sheaves

Let $\mathfrak X$ be an algebraic stack over $\mathbb F_q$ and let $D_{\mathrm{abs}}(\mathfrak X)$ be the derived category of complexes of $\overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell$-sheaves which are absolutely convergent in the sense of Behrend [K. Behrend,  [Derived ℓ-adic categories for algebraic stacks](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/ladic.pdf)].

Define the operation of semisimplification on complexes by first taking cohomology of a complex and then taking gr with respect to a filtration whose subquotients are irreducible objects with respect to the t-structure, so the result is a complex of semisimple sheaves with zero differential.

**Question:** Can one define a version of the K-group of $D_{\mathrm{abs}}(\mathfrak X)$,  so that in this K-group $ [\mathcal F]=[\mathcal F^{ss}]$, where $ss$ denotes semisimplification, and on this K-group there are induced morphisms from functors $f_\ast$ and $f^*$ for a morphism of stacks $f\colon \mathfrak X \to \mathfrak Y$?